# Tabs Failure: Polymer in Safari & Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari, polymer, zurb-foundation

I'm having great difficulty trying to resolve an issue involving foundation and Polymer (www.polymer-project.org). It seems that tabs only works in Chrome but fails in Safari, Firefox and Opera (where it behaves rather strangely).

I've put together some a simple Polymer element that demonstrates this problem which can be obtained from https://github.com/paulkorir/polymer-template

If the example doesn't work let me know then I'll sort it out.

Thanks.

Paul

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using Polymer 1.x instead of 2.x?

Comment: That's the code in development. We might/should migrate to 2.0 later but currently on 1.0. Is this issue fixed in 2.0?